# Please see the circuit diagram below and under the assumption that VBE = 0.7 V, what are VB,IB, IE, IC, VC, β?

Tags: transistors

[image]

Ve= 1V and Vbe=0.7V how to approach this problem and solve it with the basic transistor knowledge?

Comment: What have you been able to figure out so far? We don't solve homework problems for you, but if you have made a sincere effort and are stuck we may be able to help.

Comment: yes. I have calculated Ie=5-1/5Kohm = 0.8mA
then Ve=Vb+0.7, as Ve=1V given then Vb=0.3V.
I am not sure about the Ib, should I assume Ib equal to Zero and calculate further?
Which eventually lead Ic=0.8mA?

Comment: You know Vb and there is nothing but a resistor to ground. So that tells you something about Ib and you already have calculated Ie, so maybe you can do something with those ?

Comment: so please let me know if I am not the right path,
Ib=0.3V-0V/20Kohm=0.015mA and using the formula of Ie=(1+beta)Ib I will receive the current gain i.e. Beta=52.33
and then as beta=Ic/Ib, Ic=0.784mA
but now I am stuck with the Vc calculation, could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you're basically there, except for two things.

First, Vc you can calculate from the collector current, the -5V supply and Ohm's law.

Second, you should confirm that the transistor is not in saturation (that Vc > Ve by at least a few hundred mV).

Answer (score 0):

Givens:

- \$V_\text{E}= 1\:\text{V}\$
- \$V_\text{BE}=700\:\text{mV}\$
- \$V_\text{EE}=+5\:\text{V}\$
- \$V_\text{CC}=-5\:\text{V}\$
- \$R_\text{B}=20\:\text{k}\Omega\$
- \$R_\text{C}=R_\text{E}=5\:\text{k}\Omega\$

(Note an oddity here of having the emitter resistor called \$R_\text{C}\$ and your collector resistor called \$R_\text{E}\$.)

Derived:

- \$V_\text{B}=V_\text{E}-V_\text{BE}=+300\:\text{mV}\$
- \$I_\text{B}=\frac{V_\text{B}-0\:\text{V}}{R_\text{B}} = +15\:\mu\text{A}\$

Assuming active mode, we'd find:

- \$I_\text{E}=\frac{V_\text{EE}-V_\text{E}}{R_\text{C}} = +800\:\mu\text{A}\$
- \$I_\text{C}=I_\text{E} -I_\text{B}=785\:\mu\text{A}\$
- \$\beta=\frac{I_\text{C}}{I_\text{B}}=\frac{785\:\mu\text{A}}{15\:\mu\text{A}}=52.\overline{3}\$

Assuming saturation mode, with \$V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\approx 200\:\text{mV}\$, we'd find:

- \$V_\text{C}=V_\text{E}-V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\$
- \$\beta=\frac{\left[\frac{V_\text{C}}{R_\text{E}}\right]}{I_\text{B}}\approx \frac{\left[\frac{V_\text{E}-V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}}{R_\text{E}}\right]}{I_\text{B}}=\frac{160\:\mu\text{A}}{15\:\mu\text{A}}=10.\overline{6}\$

You now have the above two possibilities to consider.

1. The BJT is in active mode.
2. The BJT is in saturated mode.

It's a very simple test. If it is in active mode, then the collector voltage will be at or below the base voltage. If it is saturated, then the collector voltage will be *close* to the emitter voltage. All you need to do is to make an assumption for the moment that the BJT is in active mode and see if the logic fails or succeeds.

If in active mode, \$V_\text{C}=V_\text{CC}+R_\text{E}\cdot I_\text{C}\$. This computes as \$V_\text{C}=-5\:\text{V} + 5\:\text{k}\Omega \cdot 785\:\mu\text{A}=-1.075\:\text{V}\$, or \$\mid \,V_\text{CE}\mid \:\ge\, V_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}\$ This fits the active mode criteria. So the BJT is in active mode.

From here you should be able to work out approximate values for all the variables mentioned.